# Using Thread.sleep(); in sysout and syserr

Tags: java

I did a little experiment to try to arrange the order of the printing of sysout and syserr to the console because it's mixing sometimes. I tried this:

```
System.out.println("output");
Thread.sleep(100); //Wait before printing the error to insure the sysout comes first.
System.err.println("Error");
```

and it worked fine. But I read questions here about sysout and syserr printing out of order and this is not suggested. I'm just wondering is using thread.sleep(); in situations like this bad? I'm using eclipse and in my project I put thread.sleep before every syserr in my code.

Comment: It might be better to change this to instead ask how you can avoid the output interleaving instead of asking whether a specific solution is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `flush()` instead of a `sleep()`.

```
System.out.println("whatever");
System.out.flush();
...
```

(**added in response to OP's comments**)

Within the single thread a cross-mix of printing cannot happen.

It must be that one of the other threads in the five other places is printing at the same time.  You'll need to synchronize on something.  e.g., write a little utility method

```
public static void printToOutAndErr(String toOut, String toErr) {
  synchronized(System.out) {
     System.out.println(toOut);
     System.err.println(toErr);
  }
}
```

And have them *all* use that.

However, *let me **strongly strongly suggest** that you look into a logging framework instead.*  They cover all this stuff for you.

Comment: @wormwood Everything that prints needs to have the same `synchronized` in the code, or to call the `printToOutAndErr` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't appear to be using more than a single thread, that should work fine. A [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) refresher may be of help.

Comment: That's just a single example. My project has five sutch code. I put thread.sleep before every syserr stream to not deshrup the order.

Comment: but as you said, I'm not doing multithrad so it's fine.